# Regex does not accept a 10-digit phone number

Tags: regex, phone-number

I am using this regex to validate for the phone number:

```
^(\\([2-9]\\d{2}\\)|[2-9]\\d{2})[- ]?\\d{3}[- ]?\\d{4}$
```

However, when I test the input of any 10-digit phone number without dashes or spaces, such as `4042128246`, the number does not match.

How can this regex be improved to accept this input?
Thanks.

Comment: It seems to work to me. What language is this?

Comment: Maybe the regex engine you are using does not support `\d` ?

Comment: @lonesomeday, language is ASP.NET/C#

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend stripping all non-digits, then checking that you have 10 digits remaining. Given that, you can store it in a common (ie nicely normalized) format, and subsequently change the format later in your display layer. (In the case where you want to show dashes and/or parens.)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need to be escaping the backslashes?

This works for me in a .NET Environment:

```
^(\([2-9]\d{2}\)|[2-9]\d{2})[- ]?\d{3}[- ]?\d{4}$
```

Answer (score 0):

It matches when I try it in JavaScript.  Perhaps it's a result of the language you're using not supporting all of the same options.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me in PowerShell. But take it from someone that works in the telecom industry - it's a good idea to parse phone numbers using code instead of regex, assuming your situation doesn't strictly require a regular expression.

As Alex Howansky stated, the best thing to do is to be very forgiving in what you will accept then remove all ()'s, -'s, and spaces. Then store the number as a number. You'll never have to worry about leading 0's in a phone number that need to be preserved. (International dialing codes use leading zeros, but that is not part of the phone number.)

It's also worth noting that although I don't know of any valid exchanges that start with a 0 or 1, there's nothing that prohibits it other than legacy 7 digit dialing plans. So the easiest way to check for a valid NANP phone number after converting to a 64 bit integer is:

```
value >= 2000000000 && value <= 9999999999
```

Comment: Interesting approach. Is your note that there are no valid exchanges that start with a 0 or 1 a worldwide comment?